# How to access the variables between advertiser and discoverer using Google Nearby API?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I am using the Google Nearby API in order to send files between two devices. My requirement is that when the connection is initiated, I need to show the advertiser's name/mobile model name to discoverer and vice-versa, so they can trust the connection, as the endpoint name is not self descriptive. I tried doing it using Shared preferences, having a static variable but it doesn't work. The advertiser and discoverer both treat those variable as separate instances and they cannot be used. I would like to know what else can be done for such scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question might help someone.
As per my understanding, displaying the names is not possible at both the ends, but what you can do is display the nearby advertisers(Receivers) on the discoverer(Sender) device by using the

```
startAdvertising (String name, String serviceId, ConnectionLifecycleCallback connectionLifecycleCallback, AdvertisingOptions options)
```

where "name" is the value you can customize and it will be displayed on the discoverer(Sender) side.

On the discoverer(Sender) side, you can use the below method of the EndpointDiscoveryCallback to apply your business logic.

```
onEndpointFound (String endpointId, DiscoveredEndpointInfo info)
```

To get the Advertiser(Receiver) name, call

```
info.getEndpointName()
```